# Request Notification permission in chrome fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have written a simple script which should prompt the user for notification permissions.

When run in Firefox 43, it displays **"granted"**, whereas Chrome 47 displays **"denied"** without prompting the user (Firefox doesn't prompt as well).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        Notification.requestPermission(function (result) {

            console.log(result); // Chrome displays "denied"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: my chrome is ok, maybe it has some master settings that disable all the notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I can get the symptoms you describe if I change the browser setting to block all notifications.

`Settings > Advanced > Content Settings > Notificaitons`
`Do not allow any site to show notifications` - Is this checked?

You'll want to set it to either of the other 2 options. A couple of useful resources are [here (Chrome blog)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/permissions-api-for-the-web?hl=en) and [here (sandbox)](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/permissions/).